# Using \include with file names that contain symbols and spaces

Tags: include

I need to include a chapter of a book if the name of the folder and the file contacting in is chapter1 and chapter1 respectively. I just do

```
\include{chapter1/chapter1}
```

and everything is ok. The file name is not that do it is like this: word and word (assume it is called "black & blue")

I've tried the followings none of which have worked:

```
\include{black_&_blue/black_&_blue}
\include{black_\&_blue/black_\&_blue}
\include{"black_\&_blue"/"black_\&_blue"}
\include{"black\space \&\space blue"/"black\space \&\space blue"}
```

can somebody say how can I include the file name that has the symbols `&` and has spaces?

Comment: It will take you 5 seconds to rename the files to something without spaces and funny symbols and perhaps hours to solve all the problems involved with such file names. Do you think it is really worth your time?